# Save data into mongoDB from external html pages in meteor

Tags: html, mongodb, meteor, insert, external

I have some html javascript and css files that i placed inside the /public folder in my existing meteor app . now i can redirect to load the html from my meteor app .the url is localhost:3000/myapp/index.html .

What i want is now is after completing some job in the external html page i want store some data with meteor UserId in mongo db database .

If data store inside mongo is not possible in that case can i send the data to the meteor app and then store it to db ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: has anybody faced this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean 'external HTML pages'?

I recommend you spend 45 mins and work through the [meteor tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) to learn how to get information from templates and insert/remove from the database.

Comment: hello Sean , thanks for the reply . let me correct myself . my existing meteor project is running fine . i have put some html css and javascript files in the /public folder .That is a requirement .I can redirect and load that html in browser . now i want to use either rest API or some kind of DDP connection to bind that public folder's javascript with meteor and access the database . I am looking into asteroid but so far no luck .